# JQuery .closest("tr") is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

http://jsfiddle.net/yjxq7bae/1/

I am trying to select the checkbox prop in the input tag. The id and name of the input tag are reused, so I have to use the `<nobr>` text to scale the dom and get the value.

```
<tr>
    <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="190px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
        <nobr>Confirmation Sent</nobr>
        </h3>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
       <span dir="none">
          <input id="ctl00_m_g_ed53ee23_de9d_4105_ba24_00e2a21cef5e_ctl00_ctl05_ctl50_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_BooleanField" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$m$g_ed53ee23_de9d_4105_ba24_00e2a21cef5e$ctl00$ctl05$ctl50$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$BooleanField" checked="checked" /><br />
       </span>
    </td>
</tr>
<div>Click Here</div>
```

I have tried every conceivable way. If you will notice `.closest()` fails once I go up one more from the `<h3>` element. The fiddle demonstrates this on load by first changing the css of h3, and then attempting to hide the td.

```
var mop = $('nobr').filter(function () {
    return $(this).text() === 'Confirmation Sent'
}).closest("tr").find("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked');
alert(typeof mop);

$('nobr:contains(Confirmation Sent)').closest("h3").css("background", "yellow");
$('nobr:contains(Confirmation Sent)').closest("h3").closest("td").hide();


$('div').on("click ", function (event) {
    var toast = $('nobr').filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() === 'Confirmation Sent'
    }).closest("tr").find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked');
    alert(typeof toast);
});
```

Comment: I just rewrite using parent() http://jsfiddle.net/yjxq7bae/2/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have correct syntax for a table. You're missing the `<table>` and `</table>` tags around your rows.

Since it's not a valid table, the browser throws away your `<tr>` and `<td>` tags:

[image: Screenshot of resulting HTML structure in the DOM]

If you wrap your HTML in a `<table>` your javascript works as intended.

Comment: Oh my god. And I was just tearing as little as I could into fiddle from the source code. That would explain it. Answered.